# KIBANA message needed to be splitted using a log pattern

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, logstash, kibana

I have a requirement to split the msg field further in KIBANA logs (for service responses) as some fields appear as splited fields instead of showing it as raw text in logs.

Sample response in logs as below. (When Kibana log is expanded the message field is showing as below)

```
GET http://xxx.flmingo.com/v1/compare?details.id=30101
    200 - OK
    Transaction-ID: xxxxxxx-jhjhj-xxcc-0000-d8f5c5570000
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 525
    Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2020 00:00:12 GMT
    Connection: close
    --- And body for charset UTF-8 is ---
{"items":[{"id":"0000sssbg-ssssqs-xxxxx-dddd-503f007710c0","modelType":"User","state":"Deleted","created":"2019-11-21T04:05:00Z","modified":"2010-12-05T14:08:53Z","modifiedBy":{"id":"ddddddddd-0000-4rfv-erbs-0jhugue98989","modelType":"User"},"detailsOf":{"id":"rtttttryryr","modelType":"userDetails"},"cleint":[{"films":[{"giftNo":"11 we87yjhjb","dependancies":[{"id":"sddqdd3ed-2222-3333-2000-hhjuy76767","modelType":"User"}]}],"refugee":{"id":"sssswq-qqdqdq-2232-0000-kkkkkkkkkkk","modelType":"Userset"}}]}]}
```

I need to set some fields(eg - response code, HTTP verb, request URL) as separated fields within the message attribute itself in order to make it easier for searching in KIBANA.

expecting as below

```
message: 
     verb: GET
     request: http://xxx.flmingo.com/compare?details.id=30101
     responseCode: 200
```

currently the log pattern is used as below in the spring boot configs. I think we can give it as a key value pair but not sure the way exactly.

```
  tomcat:
    basedir: /xx/xxxx
    accesslog:
      enabled: xx
      pattern: '%h %l %u %{[yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX]}t "%r" %s %b %D %{Transaction-ID}o'
      directory: /xxx/logs/aaa-aaaa/xx-logs/
```

Do you have any idea how I need to configure this log pattern in order to meet the above requirement?

Comment: kibana is a presentation layer. It cannot add structure. I do not understand why the kibana, logstash, yaml or java tags relevant here.

Comment: @Badger I'm trying to change my spring boot project yaml file's config (patter) in order to obtain the required structure in KIBANA at the end. So searching for that possibility.

Comment: So you want to change the way you're logging in your spring boot application so you can import the log easier into kibana? But how are you importing those logs into kibana?

Comment: Yes it is using Application logstash --> log shipper --> elastic search --> Kibana. This is the way

Comment: this needs to be done in Logstash, not Kibana, so you need to use a grok filter to do that

Comment: Thanks , but my question was, Is below the pattern we need to use in the application level to give the logstash. What is the correct way to split the <msg> part of the below pattern? Using the  << [${key}::{value}] %msg% >> is correct as I mentioned below to split the msg content in order to appear correctly in KIBANA?


pattern.console: '[%date{"yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX"}] [%thread] %level %logger  [${key}::{value}] %msg%n

Comment: Instead of using grok in the spring boot app level, can we use the extended pattern for that